# Possible to monitor URL clicked inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I need to monitor when the user clicks on a link of an Iframe and retrieve the clicked URL. So far I've seen info for detecting clicks inside iframes but nothing for retrieving the a tag that is being clicked inside that iframe. Is this possible?

Comment: In iframe document add a click event handler, read the url, and you may pass this to top window using, `window.top.onIframeLinkClick(url)` provided that top window has definition for function `onIframeLinkClick`

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code to retrieve `iframe` clicked anchor element's url to top window.

#### `Page.html` Content

```html
<body>
    <iframe src="./iframe.html" frameborder="1"></iframe>
    <script>
        function onLinkClick(url) {
            // iframe document can access this method with `window.top` namespace
            alert('URL from iframe: ' + url);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

#### `iframe.html` Content

```html
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
    <a href="https://in.yahoo.com/">Yahoo!</a>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") {
                // Stop redirection for demo
                e.preventDefault();
                try {
                    // Pass the url to `window.top.onLinkClick`
                    window.top.onLinkClick(e.target.href);
                } catch (ex) {
                    alert('error: ' + ex.message);
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Tested this example with `http://` protocol with the help of `Node.js` package `http-server` which starts a server from the local folder.

Install `http-server` globally by below command:

> npm i -g http-server

Open command prompt, navigate to folder where test files are extracted and run `http-server`.

Open `http://localhost:8080/page.html` in browser and test this example.

> Note: When opened through `ftp://` the action is blocked with an exeption `Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm not sure how your two bits of code go together though, could you provide a code sandbox? Thanks so much

Comment: @cyruslk, I couldn't create a code sandbox as the online editors are not providing a feature to write file to be loaded in an iframe. Please find my demo [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_zbjmvsgIuQxE93OC6iZI8Ar-LJQQP6V/view?usp=sharing) provided details in `ReadMe.md`. Also updated the details of my answer

Comment: I see what you mean and just tested your example -- thanks. However, when it comes from an iframe that is not hosted in my local (e.g: wikipedia),  how do I know what links are being clicked and how can I monitor these internal navigation links inside the website? Thanks so much for your help

Comment: We can't access content of iframe with JavaScript when loading cross-origin. [HTMLIFrameElement.contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) or [HTMLIFrameElement.contentDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) this gives iframe's window or document reference only with [same-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) policy.

Comment: Ok I see - so I don't think what I try to do is feasible then.